# firstOrFail() function behaviour in Laravel

Tags: laravel, model

I have a factory with this line in it:

```
$channel = \App\Model\Channel::firstOrFail();
```

How is the id set?
I know there is a function like

```
$channel = \App\Model\Channel::firstOrFail($id);
```

But what's the difference to the one above and how do you set it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$channel = \App\Model\Channel::firstOrFail();
```

Will just return the first Channel in the model, usually the one with the lowest ID number. This could be used to check that there are any Channels in the database, e.g. you want to know that there's a possible Channel for users to select.

```
$id = ['id'];
$channel = \App\Model\Channel::firstOrFail($id);
```

Is the same but will only return the `id` of the first model in the database.

If you want to return an element with a specific ID you should use

```
$channel = \App\Model\Channel::find($id)->firstOrFail();
```

or

```
$channel = \App\Model\Channel::findOrFail($id);
```

Comment: Thanks - makes sense now. So it was just checking if a record exists at all. It didn't make sense without an $id but now it does. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`firstOrFail` just calls `->take(1)->get()->first()`

If that returns null, then it throws a `ModelNotFoundException` and sets the model to the current query builder instance.

`Channel`, in your case, extends `Model`, which uses the `Query Builder` under the hood, which has the `firstOrFail` function.

If you want to set the `id` then it's:

```
$channel = \App\Model\Channel::findOrFail($id);
```

Furthermore, it's unnecessary to fully qualify your namespace, so you're free to just do:

```
$channel = App\Model\Channel::findOrFail($id);
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realise it was shorthand for ->take(1)->get()->first()